# How to remove fields in child Entity?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have an entity `Image` with lots of fields, and I want to create an entity `Thumbnail` which extends from `Image`, but with fewer fields. For example, I want to inherit `path`, but I don't want to inherit `metadata`.

How can I achieve this? Is it possible with annotations?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want class table inheritance:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance

Comment: The problem is that I want to inherit fewer fields, not all the fields.